# Beam pipeline fails running with JDK 16

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have just started working with Beam

I am running a simple pipeline in JUnit 4

```
@Test
public void testCount() {

    // Create a test pipeline.
    Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();

    // Create an input PCollection.
    PCollection<String> input = p.apply(Create.of(WORDS));

    // Apply the Count transform under test.
    PCollection<KV<String, Long>> output =
            input.apply(Count.<String>perElement());

    // Assert on the results.
    PAssert.that(output)
            .containsInAnyOrder(
                    KV.of("hi", 4L),
                    KV.of("there", 1L),
                    KV.of("sue", 2L),
                    KV.of("bob", 2L),
                    KV.of("", 3L),
                    KV.of("ZOW", 1L));

    // Run the pipeline.
    p.run();
}
```

We get the following exception

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported Java version: 16
pipeline cannot run with the new java version

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of expected. AFAICT, only JDK 8 is officially supported, though, it should work with JDK 11 too.